# Deserializing a collection of interfaces

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, json.net

I have the following class which is perfectly serializable:

```
public class Form {
    public IList<IControl> Controls { get; set; }
}

public class ControlA : IControl {}
public class ControlB : IControl {}
```

It serializes *without* `$type` information but I have a custom `JsonConverter` which is able to deserialize *all* implementations of `IControl`:

```
internal class MyJsonConverter : CustomCreationConverter<IControl> {}
```

It works fine for a scenario like this:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(MyJsonConverter ))]
public IControl MyControl {get;set;}
```

However, I cannot apply the same `JsonConverterAttribute` to my `Form.Controls` property:

> "Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not
>   an object: StartArray. Path 'Controls', line 5, position 15."

How do I instruct the deserializer to use `MyJsonConverter` for items *inside* `Form.Controls` collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`[JsonProperty(ItemConverterType = typeof(MyJsonConverter))]`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute_ItemConverterType.htm) to apply the converter to the items in the collection:

```
public class Form 
{
    [JsonProperty(ItemConverterType = typeof(MyJsonConverter))]
    public IList<IControl> Controls { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly it! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what your `MyJsonConverter` actually does however as a basic example you should only need to provide [`JsonSerializerSettings`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings.htm) and setting the [`TypeNameHandling`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm) property to `TypeNameHandling.All`

This simple example works.

```
public interface IControl { }

public class Form
{
    public IList<IControl> Controls { get; set; }
}

public class ControlA : IControl { }
public class ControlB : IControl { }

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var form = new Form();
    form.Controls = new List<IControl>();

    form.Controls.Add(new ControlA());
    form.Controls.Add(new ControlB());
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(form, new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All });
    var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Form>(json, new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All });
}
```

**Edit**

After clarifications that no the type handling is not used therefore no `$type` property we have to get a bit more creative and read the raw `jSON`. And construct the object in an adhoc way. Here is an example of the customer serializer.

```
internal class MyJsonConverter : CustomCreationConverter<IControl>
{
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var jObject = JObject.Load(reader);
        var controlType = jObject["CustomProperty"]?.Value<string>();

        IControl control = null;

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(controlType))
        {
            switch (controlType.ToLowerInvariant())
            {
                case "controla":
                    control = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(ControlA)) as IControl;
                    break;
                case "controlb":
                    control = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(ControlB)) as IControl;
                    break;
            }
        }
        if (controlType == null)
            throw new SerializationException($"Unable to deserialize property. {controlType}");

        serializer.Populate(jObject.CreateReader(), control);
        return control;
    }

    public override IControl Create(Type objectType)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Basically as we are depnding on a property in the `IControl` interface (which has been ommited in the question) we will parse the json manually and get a reference to the property `CustomProperty`

If this property exsits with a valid string value (or you can use any other value you wish) we then create our `IControl` manually.

Finally the piece that handles the deserialization is the final line `serializer.Populate()`

Full Test Case:

```
internal class MyJsonConverter : CustomCreationConverter<IControl>
{
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var jObject = JObject.Load(reader);
        var controlType = jObject["CustomProperty"]?.Value<string>();

        IControl control = null;

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(controlType))
        {
            switch (controlType.ToLowerInvariant())
            {
                case "controla":
                    control = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(ControlA)) as IControl;
                    break;
                case "controlb":
                    control = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(ControlB)) as IControl;
                    break;
            }
        }
        if (controlType == null)
            throw new SerializationException($"Unable to deserialize property. {controlType}");

        serializer.Populate(jObject.CreateReader(), control);
        return control;
    }

    public override IControl Create(Type objectType)
    {
        return null;
    }
}


[JsonConverter(typeof(MyJsonConverter))]
public interface IControl
{
    string CustomProperty { get; set; }
}

public class Form
{
    public IList<IControl> Controls { get; set; }
}

public class ControlA : IControl
{
    public string CustomProperty { get; set; } = "ControlA";
}
public class ControlB : IControl
{
    public string CustomProperty { get; set; } = "ControlB";
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var form = new Form();
    form.Controls = new List<IControl>();
    form.Controls.Add(new ControlA());
    form.Controls.Add(new ControlB());
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(form);
    var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Form>(json);
}
```

Comment: I do not want/have default type information (`$type` prop) in my json.

Comment: You will need it or how else is it to know what type the object is?

Comment: `MyJsonConverter` knows it by inspecting a custom property

Comment: Whats that property? If you shed some more light on to what property or how something is susposed to determine the type we can help further.

Comment: It's not that important. Sufficient to say`MyJsonConverter` deserializes *ALL* implementations of `IControl`. I use this approach: http://skrift.io/articles/archive/bulletproof-interface-deserialization-in-jsonnet/

Comment: I have added an update that searches the JSON for a custom property then constructs the correct object based on the value.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know I can apply `JsonConverterAttribute` to an interface. However, `IControl` is in a dependency I can't modify. I'll try to play with inheritance here.