# Json.NET C#: Serialising a collection based on whether or not the collection field has been decorated with a certain attribute

Tags: c#, serialization, collections, json.net, jsonconverter

I'm building a serialisation system using Json.NET in Unity. The basic ideas is that classes which need to have their references serialised are decorated with [Ref], like this:

```
// Wine can be referenced, and these references need to be serialised as a numeric ID.
[Ref]
public class Wine
{
    private string name = "";

    public Wine(string _name)
    {
        name = _name;
    }
}
```

Any other instance of this class is automatically considered a reference, *unless* that field has been decorated with [Def].

```
public class FoodExample
{
    // This central script defines all foods and wines in the program.
    [Def]
    List<Food> foods = new List<Food>();

    [Def]
    List<Wine> wines = new List<Wine>();
}

[Ref]
public class Food
{
    private string name = "";
    // Food references a wine that pairs well with it, but it does not define one. When serialised, this should be a numeric ID instead of a Json definition.
    private Wine pairsWellWith = null;

    public Food(string _name, Wine _pairsWellWith)
    {
        name = _name;
        pairsWellWith = _pairsWellWith;
    }
}
```

I can then use either some Custom Converters (one which serialises the class instance as its definition, the other as numeric IDs), or even a Custom Contract Resolver that assigns these Converters manually. This system works great when I'm just dealing with singular fields. I can say:

```
[Def]
Wine myFavouriteWine = null;

Wine refToFavouriteWine = null;
```

... and the former will become a bunch of Json fields, while the latter will become a simple numeric reference, avoiding reference duplication. This works well because I can read field info attributes in a Custom Contract Resolver, by using the CreateProperty() override. Or I can just use

```
[CustomConverter(typeof(RefConverter/DefConverter))]
```

But this doesn't work for collections. I can apply my custom behaviour to a collection itself, but not to its elements. I could make a custom converter for the collection to operate over its children, but I'm not sure how.

It's a bit of a complicated scenario, so I'll refrain from swamping everyone with piles of my code for now, but if more detail is needed please say so.

Finally: The reason I'm not using Json.NET's native reference handling system is because we have a specific need to serialise some objects as numbers, and others as legible string names (such as "PinotGris_WINE").

Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for `JsonPropertyAttribute.ItemConverterType`?  See e.g [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18647073/3744182) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41737355/3744182)?

Comment: This does indeed work, thank you! Due to this attribute's verbosity, I've opted to use another solution that I've thrown together, but this is a good alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question:

Two solutions are currently available. The first was recommended in dbc's comment: simply use `JsonPropertyAttribute.ItemConverterType` to tell Json to use `DefinitionJConverter` or `ReferenceJConverter` on the elements of the decorated collection.

Simply because this solution is inconsistent with the rest of my current approach, and because I prefer shorter Attribute names, I'll also show my own solution:

Create two more custom converters called `DefCollectionJConverter` and `RefCollectionJConverter`. In the contract resolver, attach these to any discovered collections which contain objects decorated with `[Ref]`. Furthermore, if the collection itself has been decorated with `[Def]`, pass it to the `DefCollectionJConverter`, like so:

```
protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
{
    JsonProperty property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);

    // Do not handle properties (it's difficult to concieve of a time when properties should be serialised at all).
    if(member is PropertyInfo)
    {
        return property;
    }
    else if(member is FieldInfo)
    {
        FieldInfo field = ((FieldInfo)member);

        // Does this field implement IList? This Utility function gets all member interfaces and checks if any of them equal the argued interface.
        if (field.FieldType.ImplementsInterface<IList>())
        {
            // Are the elements of this IList decorated with [Ref]?
            if (field.FieldType.GetGenericArguments()[0].HasAttribute<RefAttribute>())
            {
                // Does this collection field have [Def]?
                if (field.HasAttribute<DefAttribute>())
                {
                    // This is a collection of definitions.
                    property.Converter = new DefCollectionJConverter();
                }
                else
                {
                    // This is a collection of references.
                    property.Converter = new RefCollectionJConverter();
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // If the field's type class has been decorated with Ref.
            if (field.FieldType.HasAttribute<RefAttribute>())
            {
                if (member.HasAttribute<DefAttribute>())
                {
                    // If this particular field also has Def, it's a definition.
                    property.Converter = new DefinitionJConverter();
                }
                else
                {
                    // Else it's a reference.
                    property.Converter = new ReferenceJConverter();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return property;
}
```

Inside the Collection converters themselves, populate a `JArray` and then call `JArray.WriteTo()`. Construct the `JToken`s using either the default serialiser for definitions, or the custom reference serialiser for references:

```
public class DefCollectionJConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JArray array = new JArray();
        IList list = (IList)value;

        if (list.Count > 0)
        {
            // Populate the JArray with JTokens from the list elements. Pass the current serializer, which should contain default settings and converters.
            // This should handle child objects appropriately, too.
            JsonSerializer defSerializer = new JsonSerializer();
            defSerializer.Converters.Add(new DefinitionJConverter());

            for (int e = 0; e < list.Count; e++)
            {
                JToken first = JToken.FromObject(list[e], serializer);
                array.Add(first);
            }

            array.WriteTo(writer);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("List was empty.");
        }
    }
}

public class RefCollectionJConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JArray array = new JArray();
        IList list = (IList)value;

        if(list.Count > 0)
        {
            // Populate the JArray with JTokens of the list elements, using a serialiser that only contains ReferenceJConverter.
            // Note that we don't need to worry about this token's children: only definitions can describe children.
            JsonSerializer refSerializer = new JsonSerializer();
            refSerializer.Converters.Add(new ReferenceJConverter());

            for(int e = 0; e < list.Count; e++)
            {
                JToken first = JToken.FromObject(list[e], refSerializer);
                array.Add(first);
            }

            array.WriteTo(writer);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("List was empty.");
        }
    }
}
```

For these converters, I have `CanConvert()` returning true always, since I'm assigning these converters manually.

I haven't tested this with deserialisation yet, but I don't see why it wouldn't work.